# Return from a recursive call

Tags: ruby, recursion

How can I return result correctly to a calling function:

```
arr_of_arr = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]

def find_all(arr, pos, result)
  if pos == arr.size
    puts result
  else
    curr_set = arr[pos]
    curr_set.each {|e|
      find_all(arr, pos+1, result+e.to_s)
    }
  end
end

print find_all(arr_of_arr, 0, "")
```

This code produces the following output:

```
147
148
149
157
158
159
167
168
169
247
248
249
257
258
259
267
268
269
347
348
349
357
358
359
367
368
369
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: What is the result that you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of simply:

```
puts result
```

which returns nil.

Also return the result:

```
puts result
result
```

In addition you might want to grab the results in the `each` statement, e.g.:

```
curr_set.inject([]) { |res, e|
  res.concat find_all(arr, pos+1, result+e.to_s)
  res
}
```

(Or break, if that's what you intended -- the question isn't clear at all in this respect.)

Lastly, if you're going to be calling this with a `print` statement, using `puts` isn't necessarily what you want: plain `result` will do.

Comment: +5 for the answer; +5 for deciphering the question.